# Python 1-lined for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm looking for a way to make this for loop "1 lined"
Like this:

```
print([k for k in ["hello", "hi", "bye"]])
```

this is the for loop:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(base["paths"]):
            print(base["paths"][idx]["path"])
```

Basically, I have a JSON sting with a list of folder/file paths, type, and md5 checksum.
It looks like this:

```
{
    "paths": [
        {
            "md5": "None",
            "path": "shared/",
            "type": "folder"
        },
        {
            "md5": "01d5c39c19f6b334145315672cf70f6b",
            "path": "shared/memes.txt",
            "type": "file"
        },
        {
            "md5": "2c04a7ccefc2596b726646f30b557921",
            "path": "shared/plan.txt",
            "type": "file"
        },
        {
            "md5": "None",
            "path": "shared/downloads",
            "type": "folder"
        },
        {
            "md5": "None",
            "path": "shared/downloads/linux",
            "type": "folder"
        },
        {
            "md5": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
            "path": "shared/downloads/linux/setup.txt",
            "type": "file"
        },
        {
            "md5": "None",
            "path": "shared/downloads/linux/boot",
            "type": "folder"
        },
        {
            "md5": "b36694d5b1ab1b2e96f197f62bb76459",
            "path": "shared/downloads/linux/boot/boot.txt",
            "type": "file"
        },
        {
            "md5": "None",
            "path": "shared/downloads/steam",
            "type": "folder"
        },
        {
            "md5": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
            "path": "shared/downloads/steam/csgo.txt",
            "type": "file"
        },
        {
            "md5": "None",
            "path": "shared/games",
            "type": "folder"
        },
        {
            "md5": "None",
            "path": "shared/games/pixel",
            "type": "folder"
        },
        {
            "md5": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
            "path": "shared/games/pixel/pixel.txt",
            "type": "file"
        },
        {
            "md5": "None",
            "path": "shared/games/pixel/data",
            "type": "folder"
        },
        {
            "md5": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
            "path": "shared/games/pixel/data/lib.txt",
            "type": "file"
        },
        {
            "md5": "None",
            "path": "shared/music",
            "type": "folder"
        },
        {
            "md5": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
            "path": "shared/music/some other new awesome music.txt",
            "type": "file"
        },
        {
            "md5": "None",
            "path": "shared/New folder",
            "type": "folder"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is make a list of all the "path"'s and I figured, using 1-line for loop would do the trick but I don't know how to do it.

I'm not that experienced with this kind of stuff so I don't know what it's called. And because of that, I'm not able to do any research on it or put a proper title.
Please forgive me for that.

Thanks!

Comment: `print('\n'.join(base["paths"][idx]["path"] for idx, item in enumerate(base["paths"])))`

Comment: Is there really any advantage to making this one line though?

Comment: @AdamHughes "Flat is better than nested", obviously!

Comment: `print('\n'.join(item["path"] for item in base["paths"])` would burn fewer cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't do exactly the same list-comprehension trick.
As:

```
for k in ["hello", "hi", "bye"]]):
    print(k)
```

is to

```
[ k for k in ["hello", "hi", "bye"] ]
```

, so

```
for idx, item in enumerate(base["paths"]):
        print(base["paths"][idx]["path"])
```

is to

```
[ base["paths"][idx]["path"] for idx, item in enumerate(base["paths"]) ]
```

...although I should point out that you're wasting the potential for economy and clarity provided by your `item` variable which is currently unused. If you take advantage of it, then in your (simplified?) example, `idx` will become unused, which means you get rid of the `enumerate` altogether:

```
for item in base["paths"]:
    print(item["path"])
```

and analogously:

```
[ item["path"] for item in base["paths"] ]
```

[Obviously, do whatever you want with the resulting list. Assign it to a variable, pass it straight into `print()` (as in your question),  etc.]

Comment: Note that you can make this even shorter by referencing `item` instead of `idx`: `[item["path"] for idx,item in enumerate(base["paths"])]`

Comment: Which also implies that you don't need `enumerate()`: `[item['path'] for item in base["paths"]]`.

Comment: My two edits were behind these respective comments by about 7 seconds.  Any more for any more?

Comment: Where do you print?

Comment: @MadPhysicist wherever you want.  Omitted for clarity.

Comment: @jez. I hope that was sarcasm.

Answer (score 0):

@jez's answer will cover most situations of how to simplify your loop into a comprehension. However, the problem with sticking `print` directly into a loop directly is that it returns `None`. There are a couple of solutions you can use.

- The best way is to stick the loop into the print statement instead of the other way around, as @AChampion suggests in the first comment:

  ```
  print('\n'.join(item["path"] for item in base["paths"]))
  ```

  `str.join` will concatenate all the elements of an iterable of strings using the string it is called on as the separator. In this case, it says "put a newline between each element of `base["paths"]` and print the result.
- The simplest way is a cheat:

  ```
  for item in base["paths"]: print(item["path"])
  ```

  You are allowed to put a single-statement `for` loop on one line. Same goes for `if`, `else`, `while`, `def`, etc. This is generally not considered a good practice, but can be handy when typing quickly on the command line.
- There is actually another method you can use, but it is probably even more wrong than the second, which it to rewrite the loop directly as a list comprehension:

  ```
  [print(item["path"]) for item in base["paths"]]
  ```

  This will create and discard a list of `None` elements of the same length as `base["paths"]` since `print` returns `None`. The only possible advantage this could have over using `join` is that it will not create the complete intermediate string for printing.

**TL;DR**

Use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with `map` and `lambda`:

```
map( (lambda x: print(x["path"])), base["paths"])
```

This only work with Python 3, since in Python 2.x `print` is a statement not a function (see [What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html))